# Encrypt data to mobile

Tags: security, mobile

I need to send encrypted and dedicated data to a mobile application (ios/android) supposing that the application is not connected to internet.

My current idea is to send the data through a QRCode containing the encrypted data. 
I don't want to use symmetric encryption and "share secret" on both sides for obvious security reasons.

I'm a beginner in encryption ;-)

I think that it can be acceptable that the application generates a 16 characters that the user can enter into a web form and then download the QRCode dedicated for this device and encrypted.

Then my feeling is that I'm looking for an asymetric algorithm that can be initiated starting from something like 16 characters.

It's acceptable that the application knows the server public keys, but application won't have possibility to send more that 16char to share their locally generated public key.

Any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the encryption - what are the risks? Before we know what you are trying to protect against it's not possible to make sensible suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your 16 characters sounds like a one-time password, from which you can derive a symmetric encryption key. Since it's a one-time password (unless the user re-uses this password again and again), there's not much risk in using it. Also you don't store this password (or the derived key) on the server to prevent leakage.

The key can be derived using [PBKDF function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). Length of user's passphrase is the most important thing - it must be as long as possible (16 characters is quite weak passphrase).